# Percentage SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

there is any way to calculate the first 80% percentage

```
select
testoo.ttamount,
egct.Category_name,
SUM(pola.LIST_PRICE * nvl(pola.QUANTITY,1)) * NVL(poh.RATE,1)
    Line_amount,
ROUND ( SUM((pola.LIST_PRICE * nvl(pola.QUANTITY,1)) * NVL(poh.RATE,1)*100) / (testoo.ttamount) , 2 )  PERCENTAGE,
poh.CURRENCY_CODE


FROM


(SELECT 
SUM(test.line_amount) TTAmount

FROM
( select 
egct.Category_name,
SUM(pola.LIST_PRICE * nvl(pola.QUANTITY,1)) * NVL(poh.RATE,1)
    Line_amount,
poh.CURRENCY_CODE




 from EGP_CATEGORIES_TL  egct,
PO_LINES_ALL pola,
PO_HEADERS_ALL poh
where
egct.category_ID=pola.category_ID
AND pola.po_header_id = poh.po_header_id
AND LANGUAGE='US'
AND TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE='STANDARD'
AND poh.APPROVED_FLAG='Y'
 group by 
egct.Category_name,
poh.CURRENCY_CODE,
poh.RATE ) Test ) Testoo,
EGP_CATEGORIES_TL  egct,
PO_LINES_ALL pola,
PO_HEADERS_ALL poh

where
egct.category_ID=pola.category_ID
AND pola.po_header_id = poh.po_header_id
AND LANGUAGE='US'
AND TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE='STANDARD'
AND poh.APPROVED_FLAG='Y'



 group by 
egct.Category_name,
poh.RATE,
testoo.ttamount,
poh.CURRENCY_CODE


order by
Line_amount desc
```

for example the output
Category Percentage

```
1     32%

2     20%

3     20%

4     10%

5     18%
```

I want to get the high percentage which the percentage of it about 80 %
so the output will be

Category Percentage

```
1     32%

2     20%

3     20%

4     10%
```

I want the output for the first categories which equal 80%
so the output will retrieve the sum of the first categories equal 80%
ROUND ( SUM((pola.LIST_PRICE * nvl(pola.QUANTITY,1)) * NVL(poh.RATE,1)*100) / (testoo.ttamount) , 2 )  PERCENTAGE,
thanks.

Comment: So, If I understand this correctly: When given a list of numbers from one to 10 (ordered), you want all rows until the sum of them all is above, say, i.e. 12 (which would be the first 5 lines, 1+2+3+4+5 = 15, thus greater 12).

Comment: I mean every category has a percentage of 32%, 20%,20% and 10%  so they equal about 82% and the last one equal 18% so they equal 100% , here i want the output give me the out where they equal 80% only , you understand me ^^

Comment: I don't understand the requirement completely. Please clarify. (1) You say "about 80%" - does that mean that the total can be either less than 80% or greater than 80%, whichever is closer to 80%? Or does it always have to be **at least** 80%? (2) If there are ties, how do you break them? For example, percentages are 60%, 10%, 10%, 10%, 10%. You will choose the 60% category and two of the 10% categories - but **which two** (of the four 10% categories)?

Comment: Also, your Oracle database version (such as 11.2.0.4 or 12.1.0.2) may be important. For example, depending on your answer to my questions, the simplest and fastest solution may use `match_recognize`, but that is only available in 12.1 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest calculating a running percentage using a window function and then compare the result to 80.

In this small code sample I've shown how to do it based on the result of your query placed into a CTE block called `your_data`. It just shows you the idea.

```
with 
    your_data (category, percentage) as(
        -- sample data based on your example
        select 1, 32 from dual union
        select 2, 20 from dual union
        select 3, 20 from dual union
        select 4, 10 from dual union
        select 5, 18 from dual
    ),
    t as (
        select  your_data.*,
                -- running sum calculation
                sum(percentage) over (order by category) pctg_running
          from  your_data 
    )
select * 
  from t
 where pctg_running <= 80
```

Actually it returns 3 rows and you say you expect 4 rows to be shown. In order to add the row where running percentage first exceeds your boundary (80), you may extract the currenct category percentage from running value, i.e. replace `sum(percentage) over (order by category)` with `sum(percentage) over (order by category) - percentage`.

HTH